# getting file content from angular url in php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to get file content from angular js url I fetched url from app.js file using route provider.I want to get file content for url 'http://localhost/project_folder/#/demoresponse'.I tried this to convert the page as pdf.How to get the file content for url 'http://localhost/project_folder/#/demoresponse'.Now I caught file not found error.

```
 app.js

  when('/demoresponse/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/demo_response.html',

  })
php
  $html=file_get_contents('/#/demoresponse/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the `#` is ignored and not sent to the web server. The part after # is only available on the client. As the server can't execute client side code with a simple get request, you couldn't get the result of your Angularjs 'response'.

Comment: is any other way to do this?

Comment: depends on your needs - the easiest way is to send the html you want from  your browser to the server